# Silverstripe 3 - set_suffix_requirements in yml

Tags: yaml, silverstripe

I'm trying to set the suffix requirements in my yml file.
I tried it like this, but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me how it's right?

```
Requirements:
  set_suffix_requirements: true
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: To me it doesn't seem like you can do it in YML, but have to use `Requirements::set_suffix_requirements(true)` in PHP

Comment: ok, thx. I thought I can put it into my yml file. Thank you

Comment: If you have the problem resolved, could you put your solution as answer and accept it to mark this question as solved please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to set this via yml.

You need to put this

```
Requirements::set_suffix_requirements(true)
```

into _config.php